# Где найти документацию по ActiveX WSH?

Tags: windows, wsh, jscript

Пишу скрипт, использующий технологию WSH, на JScript. Не могу найти документацию по ActiveX, чтобы понять на что способна WSH, да и чтобы не изобретать велосипед. Знаю, что то, что находится в реестре HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT является классами, которые может использовать ActiveX. Но не могу найти информацию для чего какой класс предназначен, какие методы доступны у объектов этих классов ... Вообще какую-либо документацию по ActiveX у WSH. Или может WSH поддерживает ещё какую-то технологию с широким спектром возможностей? Поможете?

Comment: поищите использование [COM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/using-com-objects-in-windows-script-host) в WSH

Answer (score 0):

Ищите ActiveX например по такому выражению:

var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Создать текстовый файл" onclick="newFile();">
    <script>
        function newFile() {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var a = fso.CreateTextFile("testfile.txt", true);
            a.WriteLine("Это - тест!");
            a.Close();
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Сохраните текстовый файл с расширением *.hta, и по нажатии кнопки, скрипт jscript создаст текстовый файл.  Через *.hta файл можно запускать скрипты [jscript, javasctipt, vbs] хоть все сразу или по очереди, и любые файлы *.ехе, *.тхт, *.bat и т.д.

В вашем распоряжении HTML и CSS для оформления *.hta файла.

Немного документации есть здесь => [JSCRIPT MANUAL](http://ru-jscript.com/jsobjfilesystem.htm)
Еще [Документация по JScript](https://documentation.help/MS-Office-JScript/sgWorkingWithDrives.htm)