# Привязка функций к кнопке

Tags: jscript

Вот я создаю диалоговое окно с двумя кнопками:

```
var WshShell = 
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Popup("Жисть удалася!", 0, "Ура", 1);
```

Окно выплывает, тут все ОК. А как мне на эти кнопки навесить какие-нибудь функции?

Comment: Уже пробовали гуглить или решили вопрос задать, пусть другие гуглят?

Comment: Естественно, пробовал. Всякая ерунда попадалась. Не подскажите запрос?

Comment: Вот мой гуглеж: https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0+jscript&newwindow=1&ei=GZfzXajTDsaYk74PiIy12A0&start=70&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjow9Oi4rLmAhVGzMQBHQhGDds4PBDw0wN6BAgLED8&biw=1024&bih=704#spf=1576259994016

Comment: "диалоговые окна javascript" . У меня первая ссылка в выдаче была такая: http://cleanjs.ru/articles/krasivye-vsplyvayushhie-dialogovye-okna.html

Comment: "Handling a popup box using powershell" = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017094/handling-a-popup-box-using-powershell

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нужно не javascript. а именно jscript. Скрипт vbs во второй ссылке ваще отказывается работать.

Comment: http://scriptcoding.ru/2013/06/25/wscript-shell-popup/

Comment: О, вот это самое оно. Спасибо большое.

Comment: Используйте окно HTA, там можно повесить кнопки.
[Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1100240/244950)